# Lumen with Socialite: The parameter app_id is required

Tags: facebook, laravel, oauth, lumen, laravel-socialite

I installed Laravel Socialite on Lumen 5.2, but can't make it work.

**.ENV**:

```
FB_KEY=xxx
FB_SECRET=xxx
FB_CALLBACK=http://lumen.app/auth/facebook/callback
```

**app.php**

```
class_alias('Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite', 'Socialite');

$app->register(Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class);
```

**config/services.php**

```
return [
    'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FB_KEY'),
        'client_secret' => env('FB_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FB_CALLBACK'),
    ],
];
```

**routes.php**

```
$app->get('/auth/facebook', ['uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@redirectToProvider']);
$app->get('/auth/facebook/callback', ['uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@handleProviderCallback']);
```

**AuthController.php**

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();
}
```

But when I open http://lumen.app/auth/facebook, it redirects me to FB page with an error `The parameter app_id is required`.

```
echo Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
```

returns `https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?scope=email&response_type=code`

This URL doesn't have client credentials, and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you verified that reading the values from environment variables has actually worked …?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, after debugging got that `config/services.php` was not picked (I use lumen 5.4) 
So just add in your `bootstrap/app.php` line `$app->configure('services');`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's reading from the compiled cache. Just run:

> php artisan optimize

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me on Laravel 5.5:

php composer installs socialite framework 3.0 by default, but for version 3.0 there is no documentations. I then removed the folder `socialite` from `vendor/laravel/` and installed socialite 2.0.21 which gave me the error:

> Undefined method Illuminate\session\store::set()

Just replace `set` with `put`.

I found the solution for this problem here: [a session error after updating to laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126827/a-session-error-after-updating-to-laravel-5-4)