# a session error after updating to laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

After updating from laravel 5.3 to 5.4, I encountered an error in vendor. The error is:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set() in /var/www/ostadbank.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php:137

But when I go to my error is:

> fatal error exception in Manager.php line 137:call to undefined method Illuminate\session\store::set()

I go to manager.php line 137 and I see the line below:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters) { return $this->driver()->$method(...$parameters); }
```

I am not sure where to start to modify.

See the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solve it, for more information read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

All calls to the `->set()` method should be changed to `->put()`. Typically, Laravel applications would never call the set method since it has never been documented within the Laravel documentation. However, it is included here out of caution.

Comment: Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session i did here but still error show can you mention where can i change please.

Comment: If you used anywhere like this `Session::set()` or `$request->session()->set('key', 'value')`
then changed to `Session::put()` or `$request->session()->put('key', 'value')`

Comment: Thanks @Awolad Hosain can you give me these page location i will upvote to you. please

Comment: Hi i share screen short below my question please see.

Comment: Is this your home page or a specific page?

Comment: this is a specific page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135290/discussion-between-awolad-hossain-and-jewel-farazi).